# How to get hotels near a location using Google places api in a django framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, google-api, google-places-api

I am working on a project using django framework. I want to use google places api to get hotels near a location(location as an input from the user). How to do that?

I am new to django framework and integrating different APIs and there is not much information about this anywhere.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend that you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help. It is encouraged to do some research and more research first before asking a question here. So that you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the case that you get stuck. With that said, have you checked out https://pypi.org/project/django-google-maps/ ?